# Django Rest Framework Nested Urls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-nested-routers

The models are

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Categories(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

There is a possibility of using drf-extensions, how it can be used.

How to do setup to  have URLs like

```
/api/article/92285/categories
```

It should be able to serve responses for GET, POST, and PUT

from following format

```
{
  "article_id": 92285,
  "views": 0,
  "downloads": 0,
  "shares": 0,
  "handle_url": "",
  "title": "Test dataset",
  "defined_type": "dataset",
  "status": "Drafts",
  "published_date": "",
  "description": "Test description",
  "total_size": 0,
  "owner": {
    "id": 13483,
    "full_name": "John  Carter"
  },
  "authors": [
    {
      "first_name": "John ",
      "last_name": "Carter",
      "id": 13483,
      "full_name": "John Carter"
    }
  ],
  "tags": [

  ],
  "categories": [
  {
    "id": 135,
    "name": "Technology"
  },
  ]


  "files": [

  ]
}

--
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an overview how things work in DRF, but if you are new I recommend to go through the [official tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/). I can't mention all details here. It's whole tutorial what are you asking for:

**serializers.py**

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Categorie

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = CategorySerializer(many=True, read_only=true)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

**views.py**

```
class ArticleListCreateApiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Article
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

class ArticleUpdateApiView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    model = Article
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        boby_data = self.request.data
        id = self.kwargs['id']
        # ... data processing
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'article/(?P<id>\d+)/categories$', ArticleUpdateApiView.as_view())
```

Comment: the base API is working, would like to setup nested urls like /api/article/92285/categories

Comment: In this case you should override the default method implementation of each class you use , like I did with UpdateAPIView. I updated the code.